# PHP return multiple matches same REGEX pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>71 view st, Fitchburg, MA 01420</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td>978-345-5391</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>johndoe@cs.com</td>
</tr>
```

I want to capture the values of `Name`, `Phone` and `Email` within the same REGEX pattern, something like:

```
$pattern = "/Name:<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>.*Address:<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>.*card ([0-9].*)<\/td>/m";
```

If I try separately, like:

```
$pattern = "/Name:<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>/m";
$pattern = "/Phone:<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>/m";
$pattern = "/Email:<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>/m";
```

is okay. Maybe I don't understand how REGEX works, isn't possible to have more matches in a single pattern?

Comment: Parsing html markup by means of a regular expression typically is not a good approach. It is very unreliable and complex. Take a look at a `DOM parser` instead. Those are the right tool for such task.

Comment: I know, I can't use DOM because my file doesn't have any full HTML tags, just TABLE and so on, so I can't access DOM.

Comment: That does not mean you cannot use a DOM parser! Simply embed that table definition into a minimalistic HTML framework.

Comment: I doubt it because the file doesn't have a valid HTML structure, is like many different `table` tags wit `tr` and `td`.

Comment: If the structure of that document really is so unreliable, then you certainly will _not_ succeed with a regular expression. RegExes define regular languages, those are the most rigid and least flexible structures in computer science.

Comment: 1. You can do it with a Regex. You need an `s` flag at the end so that it will count `newlines` as white space. 2. Your regex does not match. 3. It is easier to use `#` instead of `/` as your regex delimiters since you have `/` in your haystack.

Comment: You're right, you can answer the question so I accept it.

Comment: Why did people downvote the question? This was a straight forward question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example showing multiline regex. 
1. Not best solution to problem but illustrates ability.
2. Not the best regex but the point is the `s` flag at the end.

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOL
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>71 view st, Fitchburg, MA 01420</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td>978-345-5391</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>johndoe@cs.com</td>
</tr>
EOL;

$pattern = "#Name:</td>.*<td>(.*?)</td>.*Address:</td>.*<td>(.*?)</td>.*Phone:</td>.*<td>(.*?)</td>.*Email:</td>.*<td>(.*?)</td>#s";

if(preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches)) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", $matches[1]);
    printf("Address: %s\n", $matches[2]);
    printf("Phone: %s\n", $matches[3]);
    printf("Email: %s\n", $matches[4]);
}


?>
```

Yields

```
Name: John Doe
Address: 71 view st, Fitchburg, MA 01420
Phone: 978-345-5391
Email: johndoe@cs.com
```